# Can I tell if my Chrome Extension is running on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my Google Chrome Extension I need to copy text onto the Clipboard, and I need to know if my extension is installed on Windows OS or not. Is it possible?

PS. If it is Windows, then I will replace end-lines with `"\r\n"`, which makes multi-line text look better on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways, at least

1. You can simply rely on `navigator.platform`
2. Better option is to use Chrome API: [`chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPlatformInfo):

   > `chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo(function callback)`
   >
   > Returns information about the current platform.

   In the form of a [PlatformInfo object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-PlatformInfo).

   ```
   chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo( function(info) {
     if(info.os == "win") { /* do stuff */ }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks. That second options looks very promising. The only downside is that it's available on Chrome v.36 or later.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a spread of how many people actually run the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: And I just realized, another "downside" of `chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo` is that it's an asynchronous function. And often times I may need the result synchronously.

Comment: @c00000fd Oftentimes though you don't expect that value to change through runtime.. Cache it.

Comment: Hmm. Good point. I would also say that _most definitely_ you don't expect that value to change throughout runtime.

Comment: Hey. Need to correct your code example. Make sure that you spell `getPlatformInfo` correctly. It messed me up when I copied it from your post.

Comment: @c00000fd I see. I wouldn't mind you editing it to fix.

Comment: @c00000fd I've written a polyfill for `chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo`, see https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/blob/master/src/chrome-platform-info.js. For your case just use `navigator.platform` though. That is reliable enough and synchronous.

Comment: @RobW: Thanks. I would make it case-insensitive when you check for OS. Why not use regexp instead of `indexOf`, stuff like `if(/\bmac/gi.test(ua))`?

Comment: @c00000fd Because the polyfill is only applicable to Chrome, it suffices to test for exact matches of the strings that are hard-coded in Chromium's source code: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/content/common/user_agent.cc

Comment: @RobW: OK. I was just thinking to make it a little bit more _future-proof_. It won't hurt, will it?

Comment: @c00000fd There is no reason for the substring to change. Relaxing the pattern could actually lead to false matched in the future when the string gets expanded with new values.

Comment: @RobW: Well, that's your lib.